# Getting generic Oracle error message 'missing right parenthesis'

Tags: oracle, syntax

```
CREATE TABLE IDN_ORG (
  ID VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  TENANT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
  CREATED_TIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  LAST_MODIFIED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  HAS_ATTRIBUTE CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  STATUS CHAR(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PARENT_ID VARCHAR2(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (ID),
  CONSTRAINT TENANT_ORG_CONSTRAINT UNIQUE (NAME, TENANT_ID)
);


ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

I'm trying to execute the above script and getting the error as mentioned. While reading, got to know that this is a more generic error that Oracle throws. I tried changing a few with no luck. Can someone please have a look for me? (Extremely new to Oracle)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `DEFAULT` and `NOT NULL` are out of order

Comment: When you use data type `TIMESTAMP` then you should better use`LOCALTIMESTAMP` instead of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: @wernfried: why is that better ? I just want to point out that explaining the reason for a choice is better for clarity.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` - just for consistency, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "more generic error", it indicates that the order of some clause in your SQL statement is incorrect, and Oracle does not find a valid clause where it expects it. You should check the manual for the correct [syntax for `CREATE TABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html#GUID-F9CE0CC3-13AE-4744-A43C-EAC7A71AAAB6).

There you will find in particular this description of a *column definition*:

> ```
> column [ datatype [ COLLATE column_collation_name ] ]
>   [ SORT ] [ VISIBLE | INVISIBLE ]
>   [ DEFAULT [ ON NULL ] expr | identity_clause ]
>   [ ENCRYPT encryption_spec ]
>   [ { inline_constraint }...
>   | inline_ref_constraint
>   ]
> ```

that tells you that the `DEFAULT` clause comes *before* any constraints, of which `NOT NULL` is one.